# Saving date and comparing if its todays date

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, pymongo

I tried to save Python `datetime.datetime.now().date()` in mongodb using code 
like:

```
mytable.insert({'date': datetime.datetime.now().date(),...})
```

But this gives the following error:

> bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: datetime

As per [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/_Jj_yM_EQqM), PyMongo doesn't support saving date instance. 
So we can save `datetime.datetime.now()` but not `datetime.datetime.now().date()`.

Given this constraint, is it possible to compare `datetime.datetime.now().date()` with  `datetime.datetime.now()` just to **tell if it is today**.

```
mytable.find({"date": is_today ???? how ?})
```

when it has been inserted as

```
mytable.insert({"date": datetime.datetime.now()})
```

Comment: How ?? I tried this in console but it did not work. >>> import datetime >>> a = datetime.datetime.today() >>> b = datetime.datetime.today() >>> a==b returns False when a and b both are on the same day.

Comment: The dupe answers the same question. Use `today = datetime.datetime.today(); start = datetime.datetime(year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day); end = datetime.datetime(year=today.year, month = today.month, day=today.day) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)`

Comment: basically your query becomes `mytable.find({"date": {'$gte': midnight_today, '$lt': midnight_tomorrow}})`

Comment: You can use `datetime.date.today()`

Comment: @EVR, nice try I must say but unfortunately this too is not available in pymongo. Thanks anyways for replying.

Comment: too bad, I'm afraid you will have to use `datetime.datetime.today()` and `datetime.timedelta(days=1)` then